# Create local LAN for vmware instance and ethernet adaptor

Tags: network, usb, ethernet, vmware

How do I create a local LAN that will include my vmware instance and a device plugged into my usb-c adaptor?

I have a 16" MBP, running Catalina 10.15.6. It connects to the world at large using WiFi.

I have recently acquired a precision radar sensor eval device that I want to test out. Said eval device runs off of a LAN. I'd like to use my USB-C ethernet adaptor (Belkin, straight from the Apple Store) to provide a DHCP address to said device. How do I do this?

What I tried... change the service order (in Networking preferences) so that the USB is below Wifi. It says it has a self assigned IP. In Sharing preferences, turn on Internet sharing and configure it so that its "share your connnection from WiFi" "to computers using Belkin USB-C LAN".

At this point, I don't really know how to tell if that's working or not. I do know that the software running in VMWare Ubuntu on the same machine doesn't seem to be able to find it. But I don't even know what tools to check on to see if it properly vended an address to the device. Are there any?